# Excel vba if operator is broken

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I can't figure out what's wrong with this simple if a < b statement.
The `txtMax` is 100 while`txtSafety` is 50, when `txtMax` is lower than`txtSafety` then run some error msgbox.

```
       With Me
              If .txtMax.Value < .txtSafety.Value Then
                     MsgBox "Error"
                     Exit Sub
              End If
       End With
```

In this case, it should not run the error msgbox since max is higher than safety.
Please help...

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), and we do not need to see an image of your UI at all. Images should be used only when there is no other way to demonstrate an issue, such as rendering an image. Clearly that does not apply to your question at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're almost certainly *strings* which, when compared, use lexicographical sorting.

In other words, it checks character by character until there's a difference:

```
100
50
```

Since `5` is a larger character value than `1`, `50` is considered the greater of the two.

If you want to compare them as if they were numeric values, you should probably convert them into numerics forst, with something like:

```
With Me
    if CInt(.txtMax.Value) < CInt(.txtSafety.Value) Then
```

Or turn them into numerics as quickly as possible if you never need to worry about the strings again:

```
With Me
    maxValue = CInt(.txtMax.Value)
    safetyValue = CInt(.txtSafety.Value)
    if maxValue < safetyValue Then
```

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly. Thanks a lot.
This feels weird for me at first as I've never experience something like this.

Comment: That's the behavior in *any* programming language: If you compare strings, the characters are compared one by one. And the *character* `1` is smaller that the *character* `5`.